# String methods and list methods have differing behavior with and without variable assignment in Python

Tags: python

Hopefully not a silly question.  If I write

```
str1 = 'exterminate!'           

str1.upper()

print(str1)

str1 = str1.upper()

print(str1)

my_list = [1, 2, 3]

my_list.append(4)

print(my_list)

my_list = my_list.append(5)

print(my_list)
```

The output is:

```
exterminate!
EXTERMINATE!
[1, 2, 3, 4]
None
```

In other words,

```
str1.upper()
```

and

```
my_list.append(4)
```

do very different things.  By that, I mean .append actually changes the list object, but .upper() does not.

However, in order to change the string object to all uppercase, we have to use

```
str1 = str1.upper()
```

but doing

```
my_list = my_list.append(5)
```

we now have my_list as a noneType.

Can someone explain this behavior.  I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that they are different object types.

Comment: Have a look at [the canonical explanation](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 3):

Strings are [immutable in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

Therefore, they don't offer in-place modification. The form `foo = foo.upper()` is therefore the usual way to do it for Python.

Note that a *variable* is not in itself immutable, meaning that when you do `foo = foo.upper()`, Python will return a new uppercase string based on the string pointed to by `foo`, then update the *variable* `foo` to point to that new string. (The old string may then be removed from memory, if its reference count goes to zero.)

Some other data structures in Python are also immutable, for example tuples like `t = (1,2,3)`. To modify those, you'd need to construct new tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Python are *immutable*.  They *can't* be changed.  This is why all the string methods return a new string instead of modifying the string in place.  Lists on the other hand are mutable, and generally list methods mutate the list in place, and return `None`.

This is a general rule (with some exceptions): Mutating methods return `None`, while non-mutating methods return a new value.

Answer (score 0):

`upper()` method returns a **copy** of a string. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

the .upper() method does not change anything in your String but it return a new string that is with the upper words and you need to save that output in a variable.
but in .append() method add your input in the list and you don't need to use `my_list = my_list.append(5)`